# How to get size of a menu item inside a menu in wxWidgets in C++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to set a bitmap from my SVG file for my menu item in wxWidgets 3.2.2.1 on Windows 10. I am using wxBitmapBundle, so I need to know the size of my menu item to get the correct bitmap size. The code would be like the following:

```
item_->SetBitmap( wxbitmap_.GetBitmap( size ) ); // how to get 'size' from 'item_'?
```

`item` is a wxMenuItem and is defined like below:

```
item_ = new wxMenuItem( menu, menuId_, getItemCaption(), wxT( "" ), wxITEM_NORMAL, nullptr );
```

I am thinking of getting the size of menu item's text then adding the margin to it by using [GetMarginWidth](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_menu_item.html#a5d49fce4aa0446c647906bd46e86c134). However, I am not sure about the width and height margin. Are they equal? Should we also add something else (like padding in Web, if any)?

In addition, I can say that the height is more important, but I am wondering of what would be the width in case of having shortcuts?

Comment: why? Take a look at the ownerdraw sample...

Comment: Hi @igor, about "why, I should say, I don't want different heights for my menu items. I want them to have exactly the same height. That's the main reason I am using SVG. I also looked at the `ownerdraw` example but the heights are not equal there. You could simply hover on them and see the difference

Comment: This is simply not possible with wxWidgets. Native menu items do not expose this and so itws not available for the library.Even if you find a solution it will not be portable. The best way is to use ownerdraw menu from the sample and just play with the sizes of the SVG. Or you could set the size of the SVG to 16x16.

Comment: I guess you could try and look in Qt, but I doubt they will have it as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using wxBitmapBundle, so I need to know the size of my menu item to get the correct bitmap size.

Sorry but I think you fundamentally misunderstand `wxBitmapBundle` purpose. Its whole point is that you do *not* need to know the size of anything, you just create a bundle with all your resources and it will choose the best one to use automatically, i.e., assuming your `wxbitmap_` is a `wxBitmapBundle`, just do

```cpp
item_->SetBitmap( wxbitmap_ );
```

And this does work perfectly well for menu bitmaps. Just associate the bundle with the bitmaps with the item and the right one will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's right but I am not satisfied with the returned size! It's bigger than expected and cause the menu item size to be bigger and it depends on the default size when you create the bundle. That's why I am going to explicitly tell the bundle to return a bitmap with the correct size. For menu items, as @Igor mentioned, I use 16x16 px for the menu items. Otherwise, your answer is totally correct.

Comment: You can define your own bundle implementation which uses logic different from default, but it's the menu itself which determines the size of its items, not the bundle.